# Perl, Help accessing value in hash of hashes

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash of hashes, and I need to access a value, if the value o the same sub-hash matches string.

this is part of the hash I am trying to access:

```
{
  'ACCOUNTINFO' => {
                   'ENTRY' => [
                              {
                                'Name' => 'fields_12'
                              },
                              {
                                'Name' => 'fields_24'
                              },
                              {
                                'content' => 'Piso 12',
                                'Name' => 'TAG'
                              },
                              {
                                'Name' => 'fields_23'
                              },
                              ]
                   }
}
```

If Name is "Tag" I need the value of "content".

I can access Name:

```
$name = $refia->{ACCOUNTINFO}{ENTRY}{Name};
```

but I can't find any way to access content when needed.

I have gottend to this:

```
if ($refia->{ACCOUNTINFO}{ENTRY}{Name} eq "TAG") {
    ###
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's look at the brackets:

```
{ { [ {
```

You have an HoHoAoH. You'll need the same brackets to dereference it:

```
$refia->{...}{...}[...]{...}
```

or more specifically,

```
$refia->{ACCOUNTINFO}{ENTRY}[$i]{Name};
```

But you don't know `$i`. In fact, you want to try a number of different values for `$i`, so you'll need a loop.

```
for my $i (0 .. $#{ $refia->{ACCOUNTINFO}{ENTRY} }) {
   if ($refia->{ACCOUNTINFO}{ENTRY}[$i]{Name} eq 'TAG') {
      ...
   }       
}
```

But that's a bit hard to follow. A much better solution is to narrow the focus to just the relevant part of the structure.

```
my $entries = $refia->{ACCOUNTINFO}{ENTRY};
for my $entry (@$entries) {
   if ($entry->{Name} eq 'TAG') {
      ...
   }       
}
```

Comment: I am still unable to get the value of "content". I am trying with the first syntax you wrote. Where are the dots I wrote:
$tag = $ref->{ACCOUNTINFO}{ENTRY}[$i]{content}.
but I am getting nothing

Comment: Then either your data structure isn't what you said it is, or you didn't copy the code correctly. (I see you have your ref in a var called `$refia` and mine's in `$ref`. Did you account for that? I switched my answer to use `$refia`.)

Comment: If the issue was indeed `$ref` vs `$refia`, then you probably aren't using `use strict;`. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: The issue in fact vas ref vs refia. I use both in my script.
I cannot use scrict here. I am modifiying a script that does not use it and it does not work if I use strict. I have tried fixing that, but I can't.

Comment: Add `use strict qw( vars );`, but also add `our $foo;` for anything that complains. This will give you some of the benefits of `use strict;` in new code without having to fix your old code on the spot. // Alternatively or additionally, you can use `use strict;` inside new functions as you write them. It's a lexically-scoped pragma, so it will only affect the code you're writing.

Answer (score 3):

ENTRY is pointing to an array.  So you'd need to include the index (for example, get the first element):

```
$refia->{ACCOUNTINFO}{ENTRY}[0]{Name}
```

which is a short way of writing

```
$refia->{ACCOUNTINFO}->{ENTRY}->[0]->{Name}
```

Comment: Perl only needs the one dereference, since each level after that has to be a reference itself. Either form will work, but the first one is shorter.